# Best way to get data from a DataReader into a Farpoint Spreadsheet?

Tags: vb.net, farpoint-spread

I need to move data from a datareader into a [Farpoint Spreadsheet](http://www.fpoint.com/products/spread/spread.aspx) component in a Windows form.  The DataSource of an fps sheet [can't be set to a datareader](http://www.clubfarpoint.com/Forums/forums/thread/68432.aspx).  I don't want to change my app to use ADO just for this purpose.

Right now I'm looping through the query data and pushing it into the sheet cell-by-cell.  That's ugly, and I am sure performance will suffer for large datasets (though I haven't tried it yet).

Does anyone here know a better way to get a datareader into one of these components?  I'm using VB.NET, but a C# example would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the product, but you can try loading the reader into a DataTable and binding that if it's supported.

```
Dim dt as Datatable
dt.load(reader)
```

Comment: That sounds like a good idea.  I'll give it a try tonight when I'm looking @ the code again.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Saved me a lot of trouble.  Thx